# display user's profile fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

### Please read at the very bottom, I edited my post, I still need help.

### regards

I am using devise to authenticate the users and admin with (admin: true). As an admin I want to visit the users profile's pages but I always arrive on my own profile ( as the current_user). I don't know how to do...

Users could see others users profile too

***Thanks for your help***

users/index.html.slim

```
.container
  h1 All the users
  .row
  table.board
    thead
      tr
        th First Name
        th Last Name
        th Email Address
        th Action on User
  hr

    tbody.board
      -@users.each do |user|
        .row
          .col-xs-3
            = user.first_name
          .col-xs-3
            = user.last_name
          .col-xs-3
            = user.email
          .col-xs-1
          #The problem is this link
            = link_to 'View', user_path(user.id), class:'btn btn-success'
          .col-xs-1
            = link_to 'Remove', user_path(user), class:'btn btn-danger', method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"}
        hr
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def show
  #binding.pry
    #@user = User.find(current_user)
    #@user.id = User.find(params[:id])
    @user = User.find(user_params[:id]) || current_user
    @tutos= Tuto.all
  end

  def index
    if current_user.admin == true
      @users = User.all
    else
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.destroy
    flash[:success] = "User was successfully deleted"
    redirect_to users_path
  end

  private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :id)
  end
end
```

The routes
 #edited
       Rails.application.routes.draw do

```
  namespace :users do
    resources :tutos
  end

  resources :tutos, only: [:show]

  resources :tutos do
    member do
      put "like", to: "tutos#upvote"
    end
  end

  get     "/register",  to: "devise/registrations#new", as: :register
  get     "/login",     to: "devise/sessions#new", as: :login
  get     "/logout",    to: "devise/sessions#destroy", as: :logout
  get     "/account",   to: "users#show", as: :account
  get     "/login" ,    to: "devise/sessions#new", as: :new_user_session
  post    "/login" ,    to: "devise/sessions#create", as: :user_session
  delete  "/logout" ,   to: "devise/sessions#destroy", as: :destroy_user_session

  devise_for :users, skip: [:sessions]

  resources :users

  root "home#landing"

end
```

## edit rake routes gives :

```
 $ rake routes
                      Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                     Controller#Action
                 users_tutos GET    /users/tutos(.:format)          users/tutos#index
                             POST   /users/tutos(.:format)          users/tutos#create
              new_users_tuto GET    /users/tutos/new(.:format)      users/tutos#new
             edit_users_tuto GET    /users/tutos/:id/edit(.:format) users/tutos#edit
                  users_tuto GET    /users/tutos/:id(.:format)      users/tutos#show
                             PATCH  /users/tutos/:id(.:format)      users/tutos#update
                             PUT    /users/tutos/:id(.:format)      users/tutos#update
                             DELETE /users/tutos/:id(.:format)      users/tutos#destroy
                   like_tuto PUT    /tutos/:id/like(.:format)       tutos#upvote
                       tutos GET    /tutos(.:format)                tutos#index
                             POST   /tutos(.:format)                tutos#create
                    new_tuto GET    /tutos/new(.:format)            tutos#new
                   edit_tuto GET    /tutos/:id/edit(.:format)       tutos#edit
                        tuto GET    /tutos/:id(.:format)            tutos#show
                             PATCH  /tutos/:id(.:format)            tutos#update
                             PUT    /tutos/:id(.:format)            tutos#update
                             DELETE /tutos/:id(.:format)            tutos#destroy
                    register GET    /register(.:format)             devise/registrations#new
                       login GET    /login(.:format)                devise/sessions#new
                      logout GET    /logout(.:format)               devise/sessions#destroy
               user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)       devise/passwords#create
           new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)   devise/passwords#new
          edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)  devise/passwords#edit
                             PATCH  /users/password(.:format)       devise/passwords#update
                             PUT    /users/password(.:format)       devise/passwords#update
    cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)         devise/registrations#cancel
           user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                devise/registrations#create
       new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)        devise/registrations#new
      edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)           devise/registrations#edit
                             PATCH  /users(.:format)                devise/registrations#update
                             PUT    /users(.:format)                devise/registrations#update
                             DELETE /users(.:format)                devise/registrations#destroy
                     account GET    /account(.:format)              users#show
            new_user_session GET    /login(.:format)                devise/sessions#new
                user_session POST   /login(.:format)                devise/sessions#create
        destroy_user_session DELETE /logout(.:format)               devise/sessions#destroy
                       users GET    /users(.:format)                users#index
                             POST   /users(.:format)                users#create
                    new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)            users#new
                   edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)       users#edit
                        user GET    /users/:id(.:format)            users#show
                             PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)            users#update
                             PUT    /users/:id(.:format)            users#update
                             DELETE /users/:id(.:format)            users#destroy
                             GET    /tutos(.:format)                tutos#index
                             POST   /tutos(.:format)                tutos#create
                             GET    /tutos/new(.:format)            tutos#new
                             GET    /tutos/:id/edit(.:format)       tutos#edit
                             GET    /tutos/:id(.:format)            tutos#show
                             PATCH  /tutos/:id(.:format)            tutos#update
                             PUT    /tutos/:id(.:format)            tutos#update
                             DELETE /tutos/:id(.:format)            tutos#destroy
                        root GET    /                               home#landing
```

#### edit

after the last edits I still have a problem....
when I try to go on the account_path I have this error

[image]

## Last edit

Just to remind you, I am using devise:

As a user logged in, if I want to see my own profile, I use 
`account_path` (and this work well)

The link for visiting a user's profile page looks like this:

`= link_to 'View', user_path(user)` 
but it looks like it point exactly like:  `account_path`. ( So on my profile, not on the user I want to visit)

I am not sure what to use in my controller, if I use `@user  = User.find(user_params[:id]) || current_user` **or** `#@user = User.find(user_params[:id])`

I have the following error:

`ActionController::ParameterMissing in UsersController#show
param is missing or the value is empty: user`

If I use `@user = User.find(current_user)`.

I am redirected on my own profile each time....

```
  def show
  #binding.pry
    #@user = User.find(current_user)
    #@user = User.find(user_params[:id])
    @user  = User.find(user_params[:id]) || current_user
    @tutos = Tuto.all
  end
```

Comment: Not a solution but you can change 'if current_user.admin == true' to 'if current_user.admin?' for better readability.

Comment: Oh yes well done :)

Answer (score 1):

This will set @user to current user or to requested user for admins

```
@user = current_user.admin? ? User.find(params[:id]) : current_user
```

Comment: I like this answer better than mine since there's no need to find the current_user again.

Comment: I have this error: ` Couldn't find User with 'id'=`

Comment: its because your parameter isn't present

Comment: What does the `link_to` or `redirect_to` for visiting user profile pages look like?  It sounds like you're not passing :id.  Also, what's with `  get     "/account",   to: "users#show", as: :account` ?  That method directs to users#show but with no :id.

Comment: I edited the post, please I still need help , thank  u

Comment: Hey ,why did you do `@user = User.find(user_params[:id]) || current_user` ?? My answer told you to use `params[:id]` not `user_params[:id]`

Answer (score 0):

In `#show` you could something like:

```
# Assuming params[:id] is the ID of the user's profile you're trying to view
def show
  user_id = current_user.admin? ? params[:id] : current_user.id
  @user = User.find(user_id)
end
```

Comment: it kinda worked, but my `account_path` doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your route file remove 'as user do' blocks it makes some bizzare things :

```
user GET    /users/:id(.:format)            users#show
     GET    /tutos/new(.:format)            tutos#new
     GET    /tutos/:id/edit(.:format)       tutos#edit
     GET    /tutos/:id(.:format)            tutos#show
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to use the `account_path` to view another user's profile, or could you go to `/users/2` for the `user` with `id` of 2? That uses the `show` action in the controller and routes to the `user` path using the relevant `id`?

Comment: `account_path` is for the current_user to see his profile
`user_path(user)` thing should redirect to the other user I am pointing to...